# How can I align my drawer elements center in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I build a drawer as in the image using Flutter, but the elements of the drawer are showed in the left side and its not beautiful like this. I would like to show them in the center of the drawer or at least a little more to the right. Below you can find my code as a reference. It would be great if someone here can give a little help.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0EFa.png)

```
return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: Drawer(backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262533),
      elevation: 10,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
         PopupMenuButton(
                                tooltip: '',
                                child: Text(
                                  'Escorts',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                              PopupMenuButton(
                                tooltip: '',
                                color: Color(0xFF262533),
                                position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Agenturen & Clubs',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Escortagenturen',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Bordelle',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Laufhauser',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Saunaclubs',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Domina & BDSM-Studios',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Tantra & Massaage-Studios',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                                    PopupMenuButton(
                                tooltip: '',
                                child: Text(
                                  'Inserieren',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                             PopupMenuButton(
                                tooltip: '',
                                color: Color(0xFF262533),
                                position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Werben',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Werbenformate',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Preise',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0)),
                             PopupMenuButton(
                                tooltip: '',
                                color: Color(0xFF262533),
                                position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Blog',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[
                                      const PopupMenuItem(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          title: Text(
                                            'Archiv',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ]),
                            const Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            ),
                             PopupMenuButton(
                                position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
                                tooltip: '',
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Kontakt',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    <PopupMenuEntry>[]),
           
        ],
      ),
      ),
```

Comment: try "ctrl + ." on your ListView child and choose wrap with Center widget, if it worked let me know so i submit as answer

Comment: Inside ListView there is no child. children are present and to make centre you have warp all the children with centre widget.  So better approach is using Column instead of listView. i have posted an answer you can check.

Comment: @narayann i meant actually to wral the ListView with Center widget but anyway using column maybe a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `ListView` with `Column` widget

and inside Column make

```dart
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
```

code:

```dart
  endDrawer: Drawer(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262533),
          elevation: 10,
          child: Column(

            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

            children: [

            //todo

    ]
))
```

Comment: Your answer it solves my problem but the elements now are at the left because I typed CrossAxisAlignment.start but I want them to showa little bit to the right. Is this possible @narayann

Comment: @JamesJames you can wrap the column with padding

Comment: yup wrap it with padding

Answer (score 0):

you can align your element by use Container or Column in my case I build drawer like this

```
 Drawer(
        backgroundColor: black,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: accent,
                      width: 0.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/logs.png",
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Name App",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: grey,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "some body text",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: white,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      "body text",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined,
                          size: 20,
                          color: accent,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                         "some body text",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: grey,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 4),
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined,
                          color: accent,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "some body text",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: grey,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, top: 4),
                    child: Row(
                      children: const [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle_outline_outlined,
                          size: 20,
                          color: accent,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "some body text",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: grey,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    endIndent: 10,
                    indent: 10,
                    color: grey,
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const AboutPage()));
                    },
                    leading: const Icon(
                      Icons.info_outlined,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                    title: const Text(
                      "About App",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: white,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                      color: grey,
                      size: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    dense: true,
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const AboutMe()));
                    },
                    leading: const Icon(
                      Icons.engineering,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                    title: const Text(
                      "About",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: white,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                      color: grey,
                      size: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                child: const Text(
                  "Folow me Now !",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: grey),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                color: black,
              ),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Spacer(),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.facebook,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                     
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.instagram,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.telegram,
                      color: accent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```